# Как сделать, чтоб хедер и футер не перезагружались

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Нужно, чтоб при перезагрузке хэдер и футер не перезагружались.

Comment: начинай изучать, javascript,  anguliar, ajax.... и узнаешь

Comment: @Air разве тут ангуляр обязателен?)

Comment: >>чтоб хедер и футер не перезагружались<< Всё достаточно просто. не перезагружай страницу, и не юзай навигацию.

Comment: Это не делается простым подключением простого скрипта, это требует большой работы над архитектурой сайта как на фронтенде, так и на бэкенде

Comment: если вопрос так ставит, то для общего развития даже объязателен, а еще nodejs или php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фоновая загрузка страницы(старая), но скрипты заново срабатывать не будут.

У меня стояла модульная система с триггерами на эту функцию, думаю разберешься

Если что, компилить на http://js2.coffee/

```
AJAXpage = (url) ->
    XHR = if "onload" of new XMLHttpRequest()
        XMLHttpRequest
    else
        XDomainRequest
    if XHR
        request = new XHR()
        reload = decodeURI(window.location.pathname).toLowerCase()
        request.onloadend = () ->
            if @status == 200 && @status < 400
                hidden = document.createElement('html')
                hidden.innerHTML = @responseText
                page = hidden.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML
                title = hidden.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = title
                document.title = title
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = page
                window.history.pushState({'html':page,'title':title}, title, url)
            else
                # error state
        request.open('GET', encodeURI(url), true)
        request.send()
    else
        document.location.href = url #old browsers
```

Comment: Вот в несрабатывающих скриптах вся загвоздка :) А ещё не похоже, что с данным скриптом будет работать браузерная кнопка "Назад"

Comment: @andreymal http://empatio-design.ru, а так это лишь фрагмент скрипта http://empatio-design.ru/assets/js/frontend/custom.coffee